# MuleSoft 4 - how can i route the errors from Http:Request to my main Error handler?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

i would like to route my `http:request` to my main ( or secondary ) `error handler` in **Anypoint Studio 7**

i does not seem to have a **clear** way of doing it.
And the documentation does not have guideline for this specific case.

in my case is necessary, i need to know and send a signal to another service and communicate the error response, like: connection_timeout

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the errors you want using an `error-handler` in your flow where you are executing the `http:request`. if you do not catch the error, it will bubble up to the calling flow and so on. If no error-handler is configured, the default mule one will be used which just logs the message basically.

In Mule 4 you can catch all errors in your flow like so:

```
<flow name="retrieveMatchingOrders">
  <http:request config-ref="customersConfig" path="/customer">
  </http:request>
 <error-handler>
    <on-error-continue>
       <!-- error handling logic -->
    </on-error-continue>
 </error-handler>
</flow>
```

An `on-error-continue` will execute and use the result of the execution, as the result of its owner (as if the owner had actually completed the execution successfully). Any transactions at this point would be committed as well

So in there, you can set the payload to your desired message to be returned etc.

There also an `on-error-propogate` handler and a `try` scope, more information on those are available here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/intro-error-handlers

All errors thrown in Mule contain meta-data including a TYPE. If you need to catch specific HTTP Errors you can configure your error-handler like so:

```
<error-handler>
  <on-error-continue type="HTTP:TIMEOUT">
    <!-- error handling logic -->
  </on-error-continue>
</error-handler>
```

Here is a list of all specific HTTP: errors thrown by the HTTP module:

- HTTP:UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE

  HTTP:CONNECTIVITY

  HTTP:INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

  HTTP:METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED

  HTTP:NOT_ACCEPTABLE

  HTTP:TOO_MANY_REQUESTS

  HTTP:SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE

  HTTP:CLIENT_SECURITY

  HTTP:FORBIDDEN

  HTTP:UNAUTHORIZED

  HTTP:RETRY_EXHAUSTED

  HTTP:NOT_FOUND

  HTTP:BAD_REQUEST

  HTTP:PARSING

  HTTP:TIMEOUT

  HTTP:SECURITY

Each module's documentation should contain all specific error types thrown by that module. Here is the HTTP one example:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/http/http-documentation#throws

And here is a full list of core error types you can catch like `EXPRESSION` for example:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/mule-error-concept